# AngularJS Select/Options scope breaking calculator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a calculator built in AngularJS and all fields work great, except the Select/Options field is making the result not work. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/itamark/4kkCa/

When I try to put the 'colors' in the $scope.normalize function _ref, it breaks the results. When I take it out, the results work fine.

Here's the code, too - because I don't think it works in the fiddle:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/calc/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/calc/calculator.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4 offset1">
          <div id="calculator" ng-controller="Calculator">
            <form class="form-horizontal">

            <!-- Buffer for Growth -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Buffer for Growth (%)</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" name="growthbuffer" ng-model="buffer_for_growth" ng-change="recalculate()">
                </div>
              </div>

            <!-- Number of Cameras -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Number of Cameras</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" name="cameras" ng-model="camera_count" ng-change="recalculate()">
                </div>
              </div>

               <!-- FPS -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">FPS</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" name="fps" ng:format="number" ng-model="fps" ng-change="recalculate()">
                </div>
              </div>

               <!-- Bitrate -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Bitrate</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" name="bitrate" ng:format="number" ng-model="bitrate" ng-change="recalculate()">
                </div>
              </div>


               <!-- Recorded Hours -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Recorded Hours</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" name="recordedhours" ng:format="number" ng-model="recorded_hours" ng-change="recalculate()">
                </div>
              </div>


               <!-- Motion Percentage -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Motion Percentage</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" name="motion_percentage" ng:format="number" ng-model="motion_percentage" ng-change="recalculate()">
                </div>
              </div>


                <!-- Days Retained -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Retention (days)</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" name="daysretained" ng-model="days_retained" ng-change="recalculate()">
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Compression -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Compression</label>
                <div class="controls">
                <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors"></select><br>
        </select>

                <!--<select name="compression" ng-model="video_compression" ng-change="recalculate()">
            <option value="MJPEG">MJPEG</option>
            <option value="MPEG4">MPEG4</option>
            <option value="H.264">H.264</option>
            </select>-->
                </div>
              </div>






            </form>
            <div id="display">
            Bandwidth:<br>
              {{ bandwidth|number:0 }} Mbps <span class="percent">
              <br><br><br><br>
              Live Storage:<br>
              {{ livestorage|number:2 }} GB <span class="percent">
              <br><br><br><br>
              Storage:<br>{{ earnings_percent|number:2 }}%</span>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>

      </div>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.1
(function() {

  window.Calculator = function($scope) {
    $scope.earnings_dollar = 0.00;
    $scope.earnings_percent = 0.00;
    $scope.camera_count = "42";
    $scope.bitrate = "2000";
    $scope.fps = "10";
    $scope.recorded_hours = "24";
    $scope.motion_percentage = "30";
    $scope.days_retained = "30";
    $scope.number_days_recorded = "4.95";
    $scope.colors = [
    {name:'mjpeg', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'mpeg4', shade:'light'},
    {name:'h264', shade:'dark'}
  ];

    $scope.normalize = function() {
      var control_group, num, out, prop, val, _i, _len, _ref;
      out = {};
      _ref = ['camera_count', 'fps', 'number_days_recorded', 'bitrate', 'recorded_hours', 'motion_percentage'];
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        prop = _ref[_i];
        val = $scope[prop].replace("$", "");
        num = parseFloat(val);
        control_group = $("input[name='" + prop + "']").parent();
        if (isNaN(num)) {
          control_group.addClass("error");
          return null;
        } else {
          control_group.removeClass("error");
          out[prop] = num;
        }
      }
      return out;
    };
    $scope.recalculate = function() {
      var cost_basis, initial_camera_value, proceeds, props, trade_return;
      props = $scope.normalize();
      if (!props) {
        return;
      }



    //bandwidth
    storagekbs = props.fps * props.bitrate;
    storagekbs = props.fps * props.bitrate;
    ultstorage = props.camera_count * storagekbs;
    bandwidth = ultstorage/1000;
    $scope.bandwidth = bandwidth;

      //live storage
    storagekbithr = storagekbs*3600;
    grossstorkbday = (storagekbithr * props.recorded_hours)/8;
    grossstorgbday = grossstorkbday/1000000000;
    motiongbcam = grossstorgbday * props.motion_percentage;
    netgbday = motiongbcam * props.camera_count;
    $scope.livestorage = netgbday * (props.recorded_hours / 24);


    };
    return $scope.recalculate();
  };

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your code and it now works. (still couldn't get it to work in jsFiddle for some reason, but I've never liked it much anyway) There were many problems. It was a combination of your HTML having issues as well as your Angular Controller and other things being improperly formatted.

First of all your Javascript had lots of issues. I declared several of your variables as `var` because there was no declaration whatsoever. Also a couple of your variables were not declared on the scope, so they were not able to be bound to the html. On top of that, there were some major issues in your HTML, such as a random ending `</select>` tag and multiple divs which did not have end tags. So I've updated all your code and the select now works See updated code below:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/calc/calculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4 offset1">
                <div id="calculator" ng-controller="Calculator">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">

                        <!-- Buffer for Growth -->
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Buffer for Growth (%)</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="growthbuffer" ng-model="buffer_for_growth" ng-change="recalculate()"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Number of Cameras -->
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Number of Cameras</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="cameras" ng-model="camera_count" ng-change="recalculate()"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- FPS -->
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">FPS</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="fps" ng:format="number" ng-model="fps" ng-change="recalculate()"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Bitrate -->
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Bitrate</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="bitrate" ng:format="number" ng-model="bitrate" ng-change="recalculate()"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!-- Recorded Hours -->
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Recorded Hours</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="recordedhours" ng:format="number" ng-model="recorded_hours" ng-change="recalculate()"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!-- Motion Percentage -->
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Motion Percentage</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="motion_percentage" ng:format="number" ng-model="motion_percentage" ng-change="recalculate()"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <!-- Days Retained -->
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Retention (days)</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="daysretained" ng-model="days_retained" ng-change="recalculate()"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Compression -->
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Compression</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="display">
                            <span class="percent">
                                Bandwidth:
                                <br>
                                {{bandwidth|number:0}} Mbps
                            </span>
                            <span class="percent">
                                <br><br><br><br>
                                Live Storage:
                                <br>
                                {{livestorage|number:2}} GB 
                            </span>
                            <span class="percent">
                                <br><br><br><br>
                                Storage:
                                <br>
                                {{earnings_percent|number:2}}%
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
function Calculator($scope) {

$scope.earnings_dollar = 0.00;
$scope.earnings_percent = 0.00;
$scope.bandwidth = 0;
$scope.camera_count = "42";
$scope.bitrate = "2000";
$scope.fps = "10";
$scope.recorded_hours = "24";
$scope.motion_percentage = "30";
$scope.days_retained = "30";
$scope.number_days_recorded = "4.95";
$scope.colors = [
{name:'mjpeg', shade:'dark'},
{name:'mpeg4', shade:'light'},
{name:'h264', shade:'dark'}
];

$scope.normalize = function() {
    var control_group, num, out, prop, val, _i, _len, _ref;
    out = {};
    _ref = ['camera_count', 'fps', 'number_days_recorded', 'bitrate', 'recorded_hours', 'motion_percentage'];

    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        prop = _ref[_i];
        val = $scope[prop].replace("$", "");
        num = parseFloat(val);
        control_group = $("input[name='" + prop + "']").parent();

        if (isNaN(num)) {
            control_group.addClass("error");
            return null;
        } 
        else {
            control_group.removeClass("error");
            out[prop] = num;
        }
    }
    return out;
};

$scope.recalculate = function() {
    var cost_basis, initial_camera_value, proceeds, props, trade_return;
    props = $scope.normalize();
    if (!props) {
        return;
    }

    //bandwidth
    var storagekbs = props.fps * props.bitrate;
    storagekbs = props.fps * props.bitrate;
    var ultstorage = props.camera_count * storagekbs;
    var bandwidth = ultstorage/1000;
    $scope.bandwidth = bandwidth;

    //live storage
    var storagekbithr = storagekbs*3600;
    var grossstorkbday = (storagekbithr * props.recorded_hours)/8;
    var grossstorgbday = grossstorkbday/1000000000;
    var motiongbcam = grossstorgbday * props.motion_percentage;
    var netgbday = motiongbcam * props.camera_count;
    $scope.livestorage = netgbday * (props.recorded_hours / 24);

};

};
```

That should do it. Again, not sure why it's not working in the fiddle. But these two updated files have it working.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. How embarrassing RE the HTML errors. That closing `select` must have gotten lost in the shuffle. Thanks!